# WCF: Is it possible to specify default client configuration settings in the service's Web.config?

Tags: wcf, web-config

Is it possible to define default client binding configurations in the service's Web.config file?

I would like to specify default maxReceivedMessageSize and maxBufferPoolSize values so that clients don't need to constantly change the defaults

Something along the lines of this (which doesn't work):

```
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding >
        <binding name="Standard" maxReceivedMessageSize="6000000" maxBufferPoolSize="200000000" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxBytesPerRead="200000000"
               maxArrayLength="200000000"
               maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="Standard"
        contract="SomeContract" />
    </client>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WCF 4 (.NET 4) - yes: just leave the `name=` attribute blank (or omit the `name=` attribute all together) - so use

```
<bindings>
   <wsHttpBinding >
      <binding 
           maxReceivedMessageSize="6000000" maxBufferPoolSize="200000000" >
         <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxBytesPerRead="200000000"
               maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
         <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
      </binding>
   </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

and then those settings apply to all `wsHttpBinding`'s used by endpoints in that configuration file.

Read more about what's new in WCF 4 here: [A Developer's Introduction to WCF 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx) - the default binding and behavior configuration is listed there, too (not too far from the top).

Comment: This seems to set the defaults for the bindings on the service endpoint. Is there a similar technique I can use to specify the default values for all client configurations?

Comment: @pickles: just use the same approach in your client's config ... those defaults always apply to that config you're defining them in.

Comment: OK, so there is no way to specify the default values for all clients in the service's config. Thanks

Comment: @pickles: no, the server-side config **cannot** influence/steer the client side config - those are totally separate